# Powershell - Force reset password for a specific OU in AD

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm Beginner in PowerShell scripting and
I want write a script or run a PowerShell command on server to reset password to an OU in my AD.

Ex. : All users in

```
OU "Test"
Domain : MyServer.MyDomain.com
```

Perhaps someone to help me.
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,DC=myserver,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | % { Set-ADUser $_ -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true }
```

Though this will fail for accounts which have the password never expires attribute set

If you wish to change all accounts to have passwords that expire then run the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,DC=myserver,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | % { Set-ADUser $_ -PasswordNeverExpires $false }
```